# Question on true positives calculated in R package ohun

Tags: signal-detection, ohun

I am wondering if anyone has had success using the package `ohun` for energy-based detection and successful evaluation of their detection routines. I have used the [vignette](https://marce10.github.io/ohun/) to learn a lot, but I am coming upon regular challenges and would love to speak with others about it.

My main challenge with `ohun` right now has to do with the detection of true positives calculated upon using `optimize_energy_detector()`. I noticed that the number of “Total Detections” and “True Positives” is always the same, when I thought (based on signal detection theory and the vignette) that the number of total detections should probably include the sum of true positives and false positives. Perhaps more importantly, I am finding that when I use `optimize_energy_detector()`, I find MORE true positives in the sound file than exists in the reference file I have created (selection table). For example, my reference table has 24 sounds called snap-jumps, and `optimize_energy_detector()` counts 59 total detections, 59 true positives, and 10 false positives. Somehow, the package is finding more sounds - and calling them true positives - than there could possibly be. This does not make sense to me, and does not make sense based on the description of how the package works (I could be missing something). I saw on [this page](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/295/software-options-for-diagnosing-the-performance-of-a-detection-routine) that @lostanlen mentioned a problem with counting true positives, and I wonder if that is related to the problem I'm having. Thanks in advance folks.

Kristen

Comment: Have you reached out to Marcelo (the package creator) about your issues? He would probably be in the best position to help.

Comment: Hi! Yes I have, but not yet about this particular issue. However, it seems like he is really busy or unable to respond, so I thought it best to try on here and see if others have tried the package. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yeah, ohun is a fairly new package so I think people are just learning about it/trying it out now! His other more matured packages (like warbleR) have more users/resources just due to time. Sorry I couldn't be of more help!